# In Laravel why am I getting a No query results for model [TodoList]?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm having problems with my routes in laravel when I go to "/todos and /todos/id " everything works perfectly but when I try using the "/todos/create" I get a No query results for model [TodoList]
I'm new to this please help me... i really dont want to give up because i really love this mvc

here's my routes

```
Route::get('/', 'TodoListController@index');

Route::get('todos', 'TodoListController@index');

Route::get('/todos/{id}', 'TodoListController@show');


Route::get('db', function() {

    $result = DB::table('todo_lists')->where('name', 'Your List')->first();
    return $result->name;

});

Route::resource('todos', 'TodoListController');
```

model

```
<?php 

class TodoList extends Eloquent {}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $todo_lists = TodoList::all();
        return View::make('todos.index')->with('todo_lists', $todo_lists);
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $list = new TodoList();
        $list->name = "another list";
        $list->save();
        return "I am here by accident";
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {

    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $list = TodoList::findOrFail($id);
        return View::make('todos.show')->withList($list);
    }
```

my views

```
@extends('layouts.main') @section('content')

<h1>All todo list</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach ($todo_lists as $list)
    <li>{{{ $list->name }}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

@stop
```

Comment: `new TodoList` is used for create a new record. It make sense that you can't get any query model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the explicit route you defined for `/todos/{id}`. Since this route is defined before the `resource` route, it is catching the route for `todos/create`, and treating the text `create` as the `{id}` parameter for the `show` method.

Delete the explicit `get` routes for `todos` and `/todos/create` and your issue will be fixed. Both of these routes are handled by the `resource` route.

Comment: thank you!!! it worked but how do I edit the the resource? what if i wanted to add a function to the resource would it work like this


`Route::get('db', function() {

    $result = DB::table('todo_lists')->where('name', 'Your List')->first();
    return $result->name;

});`

Comment: @JoeSantos You can add a custom route, you just need to make sure it doesn't conflict with the routes provided by the resource. So, you could create a `get` route to `/todos/getName` and it would work fine. You just need to be careful with route parameters to make sure you don't unintentionally capture resource routes.

Answer (score 0):

Your model doesn't have the `fillable` attribute. Try adding

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name'
];
```

You also need to define a table

```
protected $table = 'todolist';
```

**Extra**
You're also manually adding some routes that are already defined by your resource controller like your `show` route.

You are also storing models in your `create` method. You should be showing a form in your create method and storing results in your  `store` method.

Comment: it didnt work i added it to model....got this error syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED)

Comment: You need to add variables fillable and table inside the class, not after it